# Extend 'fields' support to 'GET /folders/{id}'

Tags: box-api

Thanks a lot for adding the new fields support -- it's a terrific improvement to the API.  I'd like to request that this feature be extended to the 'Get Information about a Folder' call.  For example:

```
GET /folders/{id}?fields=name,size
```

The result of this call would ideally be the full folder object whose item_collection is populated with the fields I've specified.  This would eliminate the need for back-to-back calls to get info about a folder and a tailored list of its contents.  Many thanks!

Comment: Here Here!  Very helpful addition.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are actively working on delivering the ?fields feature for most of the endpoints.  There are some that are harder than others.   Stay tuned for this to go out soon!

Thanks for the feedback John.   Are you going to make this part of your C# SDK?

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  I added ?fields support for folders/{id}/items today.  It's available in the [nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/Box.v2.SDK) as version 0.3.   I'll keep an eye on the blog and add ?fields support for additional endpoints as they're released.